# MySQL select every 3rd result and select 2x 3rd results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have product where I have 3 group of members.

- 1st group can see 3rd (33.33%) of all mysql results.
- 2nd group can
  see 2 x 3rd (66.66%) of all mysql results.
- 3rd group can see all
  results (100%).

I know to make SQL select to select every 2nd raw with this:

```
WHERE (id % 2) = 0
```

But how to select every 3rd ? and how to select 2/3 (66.66%) ?

Comment: Even this is not safe becasue it relies on ids being contiguous.Build a sequnce,emulating row number in other dbs,and MOD that.

Comment: To get the third, you would use id%3 = 0 (0, 3,6,9...) assuming your ids are contiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id % 3 = 0` selects all rows where the id is dividable by 3
`id % 3 != 0` selects all rows where the id is not dividable by 3 (2/3 of the time)
You can change the offset by using `id % 3 != 1` or `id % 3 != 2`

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple :)

Comment: What do you mean by this "You can change the offset by using id % 3 != 1 or id % 3 != 2"

Comment: `id % 3 != 0` gives row `1,2,4,5,7,8`, `id % 3 != 1` gives row `2,3,5,6,8,9`, `id % 3 != 2` gives row `1,3,4,6,7,9`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a little PHP to help you solve this. Make your query the following

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id
```

In your while/for loop, add

```
$id=$id+3
```

To the bottom, and then set the variable $id=2 to the beginning of the for/while loop.